# Vagrant and plugin to Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse-plugin, vagrant

I'm wondering if exists any plugin to eclipse which allows to start / stop any vagrant machine.

Does it exist? Can you post me a link?

Thanks in advance,
Jaro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to configure an exernal tool in eclipse.
[linky](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-exttools-running.htm)

Comment: good point, i'm playing with ant scripts and it's working too, a lot of manual work i have written in script.

Comment: unless my google-fu fails me I think that there are non plugins for vagrant :(

Comment: so far I haven't found any plugin. I'm using ant to run vagrant via eclipse and works perfectly. The advantage of usage ant scripts are you can use same scripts in Eclipse, command lines, in Windows, Linux environments etc..

Answer (score 2):

Since you posted your question Stephan Hochdoerfer has started such plugin at the date I'm writing this it's 0.0.1/beta but maybe you can try it.

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/node/519961#.UMk63KXhAw8

Comment: cool, i try it and let you know.